# React useState hook with mouse event as value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, react-hooks, use-state

I'm trying to add in an `IonPopover` to my app. Originally I doing it by defining a custom element, and using the `popoverController` to create a popover. It worked fine but it feels a bit messy so I converted my component from a class to a functional component to use React hooks.
The [IonPopover documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/popover) show this example code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { IonPopover, IonButton } from '@ionic/react';

export const PopoverExample: React.FC = () => {
  const [showPopover, setShowPopover] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <IonPopover
        isOpen={showPopover}
        cssClass='my-custom-class'
        onDidDismiss={e => setShowPopover(false)}
      >
        <p>This is popover content</p>
      </IonPopover>
      <IonButton onClick={() => setShowPopover(true)}>Show Popover</IonButton>
    </>
  );
};
```

Right now, this is mostly what I am using. The documentation also says this:

> In order to position the popover relative to the element clicked, a click event needs to be passed into the options of the the `present` method. If the event is not passed, the popover will be positioned in the center of the viewport.
> I don't want this popover in the centre, so I need to pass an event it. This is where I am having trouble.
> I created a hook like so:

```
const [popoverEvent, setPopoverEvent] = useState();
```

When the button to open the popover is pressed, this code is run which sets the value of `popoverEvent` to the event.

```
 onClick={(e) => { setShowPopover(true); setPopoverEvent(e); }}
```

I then pass that to the popover:

```
<IonPopover
    isOpen={showPopover}
    cssClass='popover-style-class'
    event={popoverEvent}
    onDidDismiss={_ => { setShowPopover(false); setPopoverEvent(null); }}
>
//.....
```

However, this way gives a big typescript error:

```
Argument of type 'MouseEvent<HTMLIonIconElement, MouseEvent>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(prevState: undefined) => undefined'.
  Type 'MouseEvent<HTMLIonIconElement, MouseEvent>' provides no match for the signature '(prevState: undefined): undefined'.
```

No matter what I set the useState to (i.e `undefined`, `MouseEvent`, `Event`, I will end up with an error somewhere in the file where it doesn't like that I'm trying to assign type `x` to type `y` or something along those lines.

How can I pass this event to the popover so it appears at the button?

Here's the full code:

```
const BluetoothDeviceItem = (Props, { }) => {
    const [icon, setIcon] = useState(closeOutline);
    const [showPopover, setShowPopover] = useState(false);
    const [popoverEvent, setPopoverEvent] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        updateIcons();
    }, []);

    const updateIcons = () => {
        const item = $("#" + Props.address);

        const connectingIcon = $(item).find(".connecting-icons");
        const spinnerIcon = $(item).find(".connecting-spinner");

        switch (Props.state()) {
            case 'not_connected':
                spinnerIcon.css("opacity", "0");
                connectingIcon.css("color", "var(--ion-color-danger)");
                connectingIcon.css("opacity", "1");
                setIcon(closeOutline);
                break;
            case 'connecting':
                spinnerIcon.css("opacity", "1");
                connectingIcon.css("opacity", "0");
                setIcon("");
                break;
            case 'connected':
                spinnerIcon.css("opacity", "0");
                connectingIcon.css("opacity", "1");
                connectingIcon.css("color", "var(--ion-color-success)");
                setIcon(checkmarkOutline);
                break;
        }
    }

    const rerender = () => {
        updateIcons();
    }

    const handleClick = async () => {
        const interactable = Props.interactable || true;

        if (Props.state() !== "connecting" && Props.onClick && interactable) Props.onClick(Props.address); //If the device is already connecting, don't allow user to click again
        rerender();
    }

    const toggleChanged = () => {
        console.log("here")
    }

    const interactable = Props.interactable || true;
    return (
        <IonItem class={Props.class || "" + (Props.interactable ? " bluetooth-item-container" : "")} id={Props.address} onClick={handleClick}>
            <IonAvatar slot="start" class="bluetooth-icon-container">
                <IonIcon icon={bluetoothOutline} class="bluetooth-icon"></IonIcon>
            </IonAvatar>
            <IonAvatar slot="end" class="connecting-icons-container">
                <IonIcon icon={icon} class="connecting-icons"></IonIcon>
                <IonSpinner name="dots" class="connecting-spinner"></IonSpinner>
                {interactable ? <IonIcon icon={chevronDownOutline} class="popover-icon" onClick={(e) => { setShowPopover(true); setPopoverEvent(e); }}></IonIcon> : <></>}
            </IonAvatar>
            <IonLabel>
                <div className="device-name">{Props.name || "Unknown"}</div>
                <div className="device-address">{Props.address}</div>
            </IonLabel>

            <IonPopover
                isOpen={showPopover}
                cssClass='popover-style-class'
                event={popoverEvent}
                onDidDismiss={_ => { setShowPopover(false); setPopoverEvent(null); }}
            >
                <IonList>
                    <IonItem lines="none" class="popover-item">
                        <IonLabel class="popover-autoconnect-label">Autoconnect</IonLabel>
                        <IonToggle slot="end" color="success" onIonChange={toggleChanged}></IonToggle>
                    </IonItem>
                </IonList>
            </IonPopover>

        </IonItem>
    );
}
export default BluetoothDeviceItem;
```

Comment: Are you using typescript? This sounds like a typescript error.  In that case? You need to use a generic on your useState so that it knows which types it can accept.

Answer (score 0):

When I do this it works here at my project. Is your code different?

BluetoothDeviceItem.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { IonIcon, IonItem, IonAvatar, IonSpinner, IonLabel, IonList, IonToggle } from '@ionic/react';
import $ from "jquery";
//import { Icon, InlineIcon } from '@iconify/react';
import {checkmarkOutline, closeOutline, bluetoothOutline, chevronDownOutline} from '@iconify/icons-ion/checkmark-outline';
import {PopoverExample} from './Popover';

const BluetoothDeviceItem = (Props, {}) => {
    const [icon, setIcon] = useState(closeOutline);
    const [showPopover, setShowPopover] = useState(false);
    const [popoverEvent, setPopoverEvent] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        updateIcons();
    }, []);

    const updateIcons = () => {
        const item = $("#" + Props.address);

        const connectingIcon = $(item).find(".connecting-icons");
        const spinnerIcon = $(item).find(".connecting-spinner");
        switch (Props.state) {

            case 'not_connected':
                spinnerIcon.css("opacity", "0");
                connectingIcon.css("color", "var(--ion-color-danger)");
                connectingIcon.css("opacity", "1");
                setIcon(closeOutline);
                break;
            case 'connecting':
                spinnerIcon.css("opacity", "1");
                connectingIcon.css("opacity", "0");
                setIcon("");
                break;
            case 'connected':
                spinnerIcon.css("opacity", "0");
                connectingIcon.css("opacity", "1");
                connectingIcon.css("color", "var(--ion-color-success)");
                setIcon(checkmarkOutline);
                break;
        }
    }

    const rerender = () => {
        updateIcons();
    }

    const handleClick = async () => {
        const interactable = Props.interactable || true;

        if (Props.state !== "connecting" && Props.onClick && interactable) Props.onClick(Props.address); //If the device is already connecting, don't allow user to click again
        rerender();
    }

    const toggleChanged = () => {
    }

    const interactable = Props.interactable || true;
    return (
        <IonItem class={Props.class || "" + (Props.interactable ? " bluetooth-item-container" : "")} id={Props.address} onClick={handleClick}>
            <IonAvatar slot="start" class="bluetooth-icon-container">
                <IonIcon icon={bluetoothOutline} class="bluetooth-icon"></IonIcon>
            </IonAvatar>
            <IonAvatar slot="end" class="connecting-icons-container">
                <IonIcon icon={icon} class="connecting-icons"></IonIcon>
                <IonSpinner name="dots" class="connecting-spinner"></IonSpinner>
                {interactable ? <IonIcon icon={chevronDownOutline} class="popover-icon" onClick={(e) => { setShowPopover(true); setPopoverEvent(e); }}></IonIcon> : <></>}
            </IonAvatar>
            <IonLabel>
                <div className="device-name">{Props.name || "Unknown"}</div>
                <div className="device-address">{Props.address}</div>
            </IonLabel>

            <PopoverExample
                isOpen={showPopover}
                cssClass='popover-style-class'
                event={popoverEvent}
                onDidDismiss={_ => { setShowPopover(false); setPopoverEvent(null); }}
            >
                <IonList>
                    <IonItem lines="none" class="popover-item">
                        <IonLabel class="popover-autoconnect-label">Autoconnect</IonLabel>
                        <IonToggle slot="end" color="success" onIonChange={toggleChanged}></IonToggle>
                    </IonItem>
                </IonList>
            </PopoverExample>

        </IonItem>
    );
}
export default BluetoothDeviceItem;
```

Popover.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { IonPopover, IonButton } from '@ionic/react';

export const PopoverExample: React.FC = () => {
  const [showPopover, setShowPopover] = useState(false);
  const [popoverEvent, setPopoverEvent] = useState();


  return (
    <>
      <IonPopover
        isOpen={showPopover}
        cssClass='my-custom-class'
        event={popoverEvent}
        onDidDismiss={_ => { setShowPopover(false); setPopoverEvent(null); console.log("laskjdflskjf")}}
      >
        <p>This is popover content</p>
      </IonPopover>
      <IonButton onClick={(e) => { setShowPopover(true); setPopoverEvent(e); }}>Show Popover</IonButton>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: There's more code to it but nothing that interacts with the popover. The other thing I'm missing is `: React.FC` but even after adding that, I still get an error. I've updated my post to show my full code.

Comment: why did you remove this?      <IonButton onClick={(e) => { setShowPopover(true); setPopoverEvent(e); }}>Show Popover</IonButton>

Comment: Because I call the function from `{interactable ? <IonIcon icon={chevronDownOutline} class="popover-icon" onClick={(e) => { setShowPopover(true); setPopoverEvent(e); }}></IonIcon> : <></>}`

Comment: I've managed to get it working. I've done exactly what I showed above but instead of a functional component, I've just used a class with setState() and it shows up. Still not sure why it didn't work before though.

Comment: @DreamingInsanity ok I changed the code to match with your full code. it works here and I can get the event and don't get your error

Comment: What they are getting isn't a runtime error, it's a typescript error.  This question is very misleading because they haven't mentioned anything about typescript.  I just happen to recognize the error.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typescript error.  If you call `useState(someInitialValue)` typescript infers the type of the state from the initial value.  But when you call `useState()` with no initial value, typescript actually determines that the value of this state is `undefined` and can only ever be `undefined`.  You will get an an error when trying to `setState` to anything other than `undefined`, which is what is happening here.

Since typescript cannot infer the state type, you must tell typescript what to expect by manually setting the generic variable on `useState`.

```
const [popoverEvent, setPopoverEvent] = useState<MouseEvent<HTMLIonIconElement, MouseEvent>>();
```

Now the type for the `popoverEvent` is known to be either `MouseEvent<HTMLIonIconElement, MouseEvent>` or `undefined` and you will not have any more errors when calling `setPopoverEvent` with an event.